# tcl with curl code 400

Tags: http, curl, tcl

I have a problem with the curl linux command when looping it with tcl :

```
for {set i 0} {$i<20} {incr i} {
   if {[catch {set x [exec curl -x 192.168.254.1:8081 -w "%{http_code}" "http://www.playboy.com"]} y]} {
            puts "$y"
   } else {
            puts "$x"
   }
}
```

I expect to receive a 403 http code, but sometimes it works and it gives the 403 code but sometimes it gives me the 400 code that I don't expect. Http code 400 is used for bad request because malformed syntax.

Anybody knows why and how to solve this ?

Comment: This code looks wrong. You call always return after the first try, so the for is not necessary. `y` will be set even if there is no error, so your code is equal to `catch {exec curl -x 192.168.254.1:8081 -w "%{http_code}" "http://www.playboy.com"} y; return $y`

Comment: sorry I've corrected it.